# MySQL order by relevance

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a search form which searches a site content table to pull back appropriate results.

I want to search the title and content fields and pull back results in order of relevance. Giving highest priority to the title.

Say we had a table (tblContent) of

```
intID | strTitle    | txtContent

1     | Smith John  | Lorem Ipsum
2     | Lorem Ipsum | Lorem John Smith Ipsum
3     | John Smith  | Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
4     | Lorem Ipsum | Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum
5     | Lorem Ipsum | Lorem Ipsum Smith John
```

And you were searching for "John Smith" the results should come back in the order of 3,2,1,5

How is this possible?

Comment: How large is the table?

Comment: ~150 rows currently. It's a fairly small site so will never get near even 1k rows

Comment: See that, maybe it might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35512410/1673161

Comment: A good explanation of the multi-index relevance solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547542/how-can-i-manipulate-mysql-fulltext-search-relevance-to-make-one-field-more-val

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I managed to get pretty spot on with this:

```
SELECT *, 
( (1.3 * (MATCH(strTitle) AGAINST ('+john+smith' IN BOOLEAN MODE))) + (0.6 * (MATCH(txtContent) AGAINST ('+john+smith' IN BOOLEAN MODE)))) AS relevance 
FROM content 
WHERE (MATCH(strTitle,txtContent) AGAINST ('+john+smith' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ) 
ORDER BY relevance DESC
```

Comment: Some things weigh more than others if he uses 1.3 and .6 The numbers are his preference

Comment: This method is great, but produces non-deterministic ordering of results that have the same exact relevance score. To work around that, add more order-by columns.

Comment: I have checked it, using this method the query time is 0.094 seconds, while using the case method below it's 0.063 seconds, and the accuracy of results is better in case method

Comment: I have no idea what's happening in this query. Can someone please add documentation in it.

Comment: @FaizanAnwerAliRupani it's using a fulltext index. You have to create the index first, then you can use the MATCH operator. One oddity in MySQL is that you cannot order by the MATCH column unless you include it in the SELECT statement.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-natural-language.html

Comment: @FaizanAnwerAliRupani When we ORDER BY relevance DESC can we order it to the another column in that relevance. In my query I need to display latest relevant records based on the posted_date.

Answer (score 5):

mysql fulltext search is a good thing but it has a limit of minimum 4 characters word to be indexed. Al tough the limit can be changed but changing server variables isn't possible in all scenarios.
   In such a situation, I recommend the solution suggested in order by case

```
select 
    *
from
mytable a
WHERE
    (a.title like 'somthing%'
    OR a.title like '%somthing%'
    OR a.title like 'somthing%')
ORDER BY case
WHEN a.title LIKE 'somthing%' THEN 1
WHEN a.title LIKE '%somthing%' THEN 2
WHEN a.title LIKE '%somthing' THEN 3
ELSE 4 END;
```

Comment: LIKE operators are incredibly slow once you scale. And the minimum of 4 characters is just the default setting for MyISAM tables. The default is 3 characters for InnoDB, but in any case you can change the configuration to allow 2 character words:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_min_token_size

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len

Answer (score 3):

There is probably a more efficient way and given the search string could be more than 2 words this probably isn't feasible, but i'd do something like

```
ORDER BY CASE 
 WHEN strTitle LIKE '%John Smith%' THEN 1
 WHEN txtContent LIKE '%John Smith%' THEN 2
 WHEN strTitle LIKE '%Smith John%' THEN 3
 WHEN txtContent LIKE '%Smith John%' THEN 4
ELSE 5 END
```

Comment: I like the idea but as you mention the search could be an unlimited number of words as it is coming from a search input

Comment: @Fraser you should never give user an oportunity of anything unlimited. Anyway I dont see problem with query contatenate :) (you can use dynamic placeholder, dynamicly sanitize user data and dynamicly concatenate query :)

Answer (score 0):

What about something along the lines of

```
SELECT INT(id), strTitle, txtContent
FROM tblContent
WHERE name like '%John%'
GROUP BY strTitle
ORDER BY CASE WHEN strTitle like 'John %' THEN 0
           WHEN strTitle like 'John%' THEN 1
           WHEN strTitle like '% John%' THEN 2
           ELSE 3
      END, strTitle
```

Comment: The issue is that the search criteria is to come from a user populated search input so the correct solution needs to be able to handle anything the user throws at it

Answer (score 0):

**Working....**

```
SELECT * FROM prospecto 
WHERE prospecto.usuario='3339'  AND 
(CONCAT(TRIM(nombre),' ', TRIM(apellidos)) LIKE '%Jose lopez%' 
OR prospecto.email LIKE '%Jose lopez%' 
OR prospecto.info LIKE '%Jose lopez%' 
OR prospecto.ciudad LIKE '%Jose lopez%' 
OR prospecto.estado LIKE '%Jose lopez%' 
OR prospecto.pais LIKE '%Jose lopez%') 
ORDER BY CASE 
WHEN CONCAT(TRIM(nombre),' ', TRIM(apellidos)) LIKE 'Jose lopez' THEN '1' 
WHEN CONCAT(TRIM(nombre),' ', TRIM(apellidos)) LIKE 'Jose lopez%' THEN '2' 
WHEN CONCAT(TRIM(nombre),' ', TRIM(apellidos)) LIKE '%Jose lopez' THEN '3' 
WHEN CONCAT(TRIM(nombre),' ', TRIM(apellidos)) LIKE '%Jose lopez%' THEN '4' 
ELSE '5' END
```