# Sorty by best results

Tags: mysql

Have mysql table with field 'descript' and these sample values.

```
malik
ali
dali
other ali
```

Have mysql query like:

```
select * from table where descript like '%ali%'
```

Is it possible to sort select results buy the most relevant?
So in this example I would like to have it:
1. ali
2. other ali
3. dali / malik ...

Comment: You need a [full text index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) on the `descript` column. Optionally, if you want first-rate text relevancy searching I'd recommend a tool specifically built for the job, like [elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL order by relevance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15026244/mysql-order-by-relevance)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `CASE` expression to calculate relevance for different types of matches, and order by that.

```
ORDER BY CASE
    WHEN descript = 'ali' THEN 1 -- exact match
    WHEN descript REGEXP '[[:<:]]ali[[:>:]]' THEN 2 -- whole word
    ELSE 3 -- anything else
END ASC
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ced4f7/4)

Answer (score 0):

You could  use locate for retrive the position oof the first occurence of the string and use like nest result

```
select * from table where descript like '%ali%'
order by locate('ali', descript) asc
```

Comment: That will show `dali` and `malik` before `other ali`.