# Search Engine Mysql+PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a little issue related to a search Engine I'm developing. I have a Table where I store a set of info. The main Fields are 'title' and 'description', where users make their searches based on these fields content.

Here is the query I use. Of course I have setup the Table Index 'title, description' as FullText.

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *,
                     MATCH(title) AGAINST (:terms IN BOOLEAN MODE) as relevancy_titulo,
                     MATCH(description) AGAINST (:terms IN BOOLEAN MODE) as relevancy

                FROM list WHERE MATCH(title, description) AGAINST (:terms IN BOOLEAN MODE)
                ORDER BY relevancy_titulo+relevancy DESC
```

The question is that I need to enhance the relevancy giving more weight to the title than the description.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/600915/3574819

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I manipulate MySQL fulltext search relevance to make one field more 'valuable' than another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/547542/how-can-i-manipulate-mysql-fulltext-search-relevance-to-make-one-field-more-val)