# sqlite weight the matches in full text search

Tags: android, sqlite, indexing, full-text-search, relevance

I have a fts3 table like this:

```
 CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE docs USING fts3(id, title, body);
```

I want to make weight the matches in title higher than those in content like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/547542/how-can-i-manipulate-mysql-fulltext-search-relevance-to-make-one-field-more-val)

What I did:

```
    SELECT    
          case when title match 'word' then 1 else 0 end as titleRank,  
          case when body match 'word' then 1 else 0 end as contentRank      
          docs.*  
    FROM  docs  
    WHERE title match 'word' OR body match 'word'
    ORDER BY titleRank desc, contentRank desc
```

But seems the `select case` doesn't work with full text search (I use [this tool](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/), there is no error, no response from this query, but if I remove `select case`, it works)

Where am I wrong?

Comment: 1. Your `id` column will be full-text-indexed; [it is not a key](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_1_3). 2. See the [matchinfo function](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#matchinfo).

Comment: @CL. sorry, I don't understand how the matchinfo can solve my problem. Can you explain it?

Comment: It can return information about which phrase appears in which column.

Comment: @CL. well, look like it needs to use programming language to read the result of matchinfo. I can't use this result on the next query

Answer (score 4):

There is this [offsets function](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#offsets) that might be useful. In your case, you know the title column is index 1 and the body column is index 2, so you could write this:

```
SELECT *
FROM docs
WHERE docs MATCH 'title:word OR body:word'
ORDER BY SUBSTR(OFFSETS(docs), 1, 1), id;
```

This will order rows that have a match in column 1 (title) before those with a match in column 2 (body).

(Edited the location of the closing parentheses on the OFFSETS() function.)